# Why does onclick() function run automatically without clicking

Tags: javascript

I am wondering why doStuff() is called without clicking.

```
function pageReady() {
  var buttonBox = document.getElementById("buttonBox");
  buttonBox.onclick = doStuff();

  function doStuff() {
    buttonBox.style.background = "orange";
    buttonBox.style.width = "600px";
    buttonBox.innerHTML = "<h2>SURPRISE!!</h2>";
  }

}
```

Comment: `doStuff()` _calls_ the function and sets `onclick` to its _return value_ (`undefined`).  You want `buttonBox.onclick = doStuff;`.

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking the function, you should change

```
buttonBox.onclick = doStuff()
```

to

```
buttonBox.onclick = doStuff;
```

Now you're passing the function to the handler without invoking it.